# How to ensure that a lookup on child must be choosing a parent of same record type as its child?

Tags: record-type, master-detail, lookup-filter

[image]I am having record type : A and B on both parent and child,and a Master-Detail relationship among them.
How can I ensure that child can only select records of parent,which are of same record type?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using lookup filters. Your filter will look like

```
RecordType.Name ==  Account__r.RecordType.Name
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,its not working for me.

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena do you have any RecordType on child: because you are getting exception?